# Change response in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a Chrome extension. I only don't understand if/how I can change a response body in Chrome.

**Example**:
A website does an XMLhttpRequest to `example.com/is_logged_in.php`. This returns `0`. I want to make a script that auto changes the `0` to an `1`. And not by changing the javascript that makes the call, but by changing the response body, so the javascript thinks it recieved a `1`.

I know you can change the response headers with [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) but I want to change the response body, not the response headers.

It's currently possible by changing your `hosts file` so `example.com` 'redirects' to your own hosting. Then you create `is_logged_in.php` and set the content to `1`. The script then thinks the user is logged in. I have checked it, and this works. But now I want this in a Chrome extension so it is more user friendly.

Can Chrome change a response (body, not its headers) and if so, how?

Comment: I hope I made it more clear now. Can somebody please say what isn't clear now, or reopen the topic?

Answer (score 2):

According to this active chromium [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058) you cannot for now modify the response body in a JavaScript extension.

If you really want to do that, a possible way could be using [NPAPI Plugins](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html), but unfortunately it's not an option in my case because of the security issues.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can manipulate response of Body URL etc with chrome extensions, have a look at these API.

## Related API(s)

- [Web Request](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)
- [Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)

Comment: With the chrome.webRequest as well as with the chrome.declarativeWebRequest you can not change response body